# Is it possible to test for reaction time differences in 2 conditions in LMMs`?

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have a question regarding possible hypothesis testing with LMMs. I`m using LMER in R and I`d like to test whether the reaction time difference between two conditions is predicted by another variable (continuous) using the lmer- Command. However, I`m not sure whether and how it is possible to test for condition-differences (binary variable:  condition a, condition b) on another variable (reaction time).

Usually the formula looks like this: 
lmer(log(latency) ~ Condition + Priming + (1|subj) + (1|cra), data=data)

But this doesn´t test for the reaction time difference between the two conditions but just for reaction time differences in general. 
Is this possible? and if yes, how?

Thanks a lot in advance, 
best,
Maxi

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by reaction time differences in general.

Comment: if latency is your reaction time variable then the coefficient for Condition (and it's SE) should give you information of differences between the conditions